# Django: Change URL's keyword argument on current language

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have these two keyword arguments

```
sitemap_en = {
    "blog_en":BlogSiteMap('en'), 
     ...
}

sitemap_ja = {
    "blog_ja":BlogSiteMap('ja'), 
     ...
}
```

I want to have this condition in urls.py,

```
if current_language == "en":
    sitemaps = sitemap_en
else:
    sitemaps = sitemap_ja

url(r'^sitemap.xml/$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='sitemap')
```

I know if else will not be executed but i want to have this in my url. SO anyone help me how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Urls are parsed before any request is processed.

A simple solution is to **decorate django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemaps**:

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap

def locale_sitemaps(request):
    # assuming you make a "sitemaps" dict here of {language_code: sitemap}
    return sitemap(request, sitemaps=sitemaps[request.LANGUAGE_CODE])
```

Then, make your URL to use this view:

```
url(r'^sitemap.xml/$', 'views.locale_sitemaps', name='sitemap')
```

Comment: I am using django-localeurl but it shows invalid urls in sitemap

Comment: I see, then why not generate one url per lang ?

Comment: yes, i have this option but I am looking to do in single URL!